Demonstrate that a straight line is the shortest curve that connects two points
I know that there is a simple geometric demonstration based on the triangle inequality, but I am looking for a demonstration based on calculus.
I know that I can use Euler-Lagrange equations, but I am looking for something more intuitive. If there is any.

Euler-Lagrange equations are the most intuitive you can have!

The method using triangle inequality is pretty intuitive...

@hamam_Abdallah f'(X) is not 0 though. It is constant.

@K.Jiang As I mentioned, I known that using the triangle inequality the demonstration is pretty simple, but I'd like one based on calculus, but not on calculus of variations.

Let $\gamma$ parameterize a smooth curve that passes through points $\gamma(a)$ and $\gamma(b)$. From differential geometry, the arclength of the curve from $\gamma(a)$ to $\gamma(b)$ is given by
$$
S=\int^{b}_a\lVert\gamma'(u)\rVert du.
$$
Using Cauchy-Schwarz, you can show that for any $v\in\mathbb R^n$ with $\lVert v\rVert=1$ we have
$$
(\gamma(b)-\gamma(a))\cdot v=\int^b_a\gamma'(u)\cdot v du\le\int^b_a\lVert\gamma'(u)\rVert du=S.\tag{1}
$$
If we set $v=\frac{(\gamma(b)-\gamma(a))}{\lVert(\gamma(b)-\gamma(a))\rVert}$ so that $\lVert v\rVert=1$, we find
$$
(\gamma(b)-\gamma(a))\cdot v=\lVert\gamma(b)-\gamma(a)\rVert.
$$
Then, $(1)$ becomes
$$
\lVert\gamma(b)-\gamma(a)\rVert\le S.
$$
Thus, $S$ has lower bound $\lVert\gamma(b)-\gamma(a)\rVert$, which is the length of a straight line from $\gamma(a)$ to $\gamma(b)$.

The length of a curve $[a,b]\ni t\mapsto \gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ can be defined as
$$\lim_{\max\Delta t_i\to 0}\sum_{i=1}^n\|\gamma(t_i)-\gamma(t_{i-1})\|$$ where $a=t_0<t_1<\ldots t_{n-1}<t_n=b$ and $\Delta t_i=t_i-t_{i-1}.$ The function $t\mapsto\gamma(t)$ doesn't need to be differentiable. The continuity (or Riemann integrability) suffices.
WLOG we may assume that $\gamma(a)=(0,0)$ and $\gamma(b)=(l,0).$ We have
$$\|\gamma(t_i)-\gamma(t_{i-1})\|=\sqrt{[x(t_i)-x(t_{i-1})]^2+[y(t_i)-y(t_{i-1})]^2}\\ \ge |x(t_i)-x(t_{i-1})|\ge x(t_i)-x(t_{i-1})$$ Therefore
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\|\gamma(t_i)-\gamma(t_{i-1})\|
\ge \sum_{i=1}^n[x(t_i)-x(t_{i-1})]=l$$

Is there a typo in your formula? Some ( are not closed...

I hope there are no more misprints.
